# dev/rfkill and PyRIC library, rfkill.py: rfkill_list() problem not all devices found

Tags: kali-linux, python, network-interface, devices

I am playing with a piece of code from : https://github.com/wraith-wireless/PyRIC/blob/master/pyric/utils/rfkill.py, trying to get `rfkill_list()`

using Kali-linux (should be Debian rolling ... ??)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""
 https://github.com/wraith-wireless/PyRIC/blob/master/pyric/utils/rfkill.py

 rfkill writes and reads rfkill_event structures to /dev/rfkill using fcntl
 Results and useful information can be found in /sys/class/rfkill which contains
 one or more rfkill<n> directories where n is the index of each 'wireless'
 device. In each rfkill<n> are several files some of which are:
  o type: type of device i.e. wlan, bluetooth etc
  o name: in the case of 802.11 cards this is the physical name
"""

dpath = '/dev/rfkill'
spath = '/sys/class/rfkill'
ipath = 'sys/class/ieee80211' # directory of physical indexes


import sys

_PY3_ = sys.version_info.major == 3

RFKILL_STATE = [False,True] # Unblocked = 0, Blocked = 1

import fcntl
import os
import struct
import pyric
import errno
import pyric.net.wireless.rfkill_h as rfkh

def getname(idx):
    """
     returns the phyical name of the device
     :param idx: rfkill index
     :returns: the name of the device
    """
    fin = None
    try:
        fin = open(os.path.join(spath,"rfkill{0}".format(idx),'name'),'r')
        return fin.read().strip()
    except IOError:
        raise pyric.error(errno.EINVAL,"No device at {0}".format(idx))
    finally:
        if fin: fin.close()
        
        
        
def rfkill_list():
    """
     list rfkill event structures (rfkill list)
     :returns: a dict of dicts name -> {idx,type,soft,hard}
    """
    rfks = {}
    fin = open(dpath,'r') # this will raise an IOError if rfkill is not supported
    flags = fcntl.fcntl(fin.fileno(),fcntl.F_GETFL)
    
    print('flags : ', flags, 'rfkh : ', rfkh.RFKILLEVENTLEN)
    
    fcntl.fcntl(fin.fileno(),fcntl.F_SETFL,flags|os.O_NONBLOCK)
    while True:
        try:
            stream = fin.read(rfkh.RFKILLEVENTLEN)
            
            print('stream : ',type(stream), ' len ; ', len(stream), bytes(stream,'ascii'))
            
            if _PY3_:
                # noinspection PyArgumentList
                stream = bytes(stream,'ascii')
                if len(stream) < rfkh.RFKILLEVENTLEN: raise IOError('python 3')
            idx,t,op,s,h = struct.unpack(rfkh.rfk_rfkill_event,stream)
            if op == rfkh.RFKILL_OP_ADD:
                rfks[getname(idx)] = {'idx':idx,
                                      'type':rfkh.RFKILL_TYPES[t],
                                      'soft':RFKILL_STATE[s],
                                      'hard':RFKILL_STATE[h]}
        except IOError as excp:
            print('error ',excp)
            break
    fin.close()
    return rfks
    
    
print(rfkill_list())
```

I am not sure about it, but I would expect the code to print out a dict of dicts containing all my wireless interfaces as `rfkill list` produces :

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: phy1: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: phy2: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

but running my script (as above) gives me:

`{'phy0': {'idx': 0, 'type': 'wlan', 'soft': False, 'hard': False}}`

according to : https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/rfkill.h

```
* Structure used for userspace communication on /dev/rfkill,
 * used for events from the kernel and control to the kernel.
 */
struct rfkill_event {
    __u32 idx;
    __u8  type;
    __u8  op;
    __u8  soft;
    __u8  hard;
} __attribute__((packed));
```

while my script gives as streams:

```
stream :  <class 'str'>  len ;  8 b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00'
stream :  <class 'str'>  len ;  8 b'\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00'
stream :  <class 'str'>  len ;  8 b'\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00'
```

and using another script to read entire `dev/rfkill` I got:

```
len stream decoded : --->  27
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Am I missing something ? Is it the expected result, why I don't get both phy0, phy1 and phy2 ?

It seems like an extra byte is sandwiched in the API between each `phy#`.

Am I reading `dev/rfill` in the wrong way ?

Please let me know what is wrong with my code.

about the code :

```
rfk_rfkill_event = "IBBBB"  #(that should be the same of "@IBBBB" )
RFKILLEVENTLEN = struct.calcsize(rfk_rfkill_event)
```

are what is inside `rfkh.RFKILLEVENTLEN`

Comment: @user:117549 Hi Jeff thanks for editing, solved my problem see: https://github.com/wifiphisher/wifiphisher/issues/1444, could be that RFKILLEVENTLEN = struct.calcsize(rfk_rfkill_event) ----> is 9 instead of 8